# How to take mysql backup or Restore with 'SPACE' in the given path C#

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

When i'm trying to take a database Backup or Restore means it is not working properly. because the path which i given contains 'SPACE'

BackUp/RestoreFile Path: "*C:\Documents and Settings\prabhu\Desktop\Backup.sql*"
(**Documents and Settings** contains 'SPACE')

I'm Working in C#.

**CODE:**

```
string directoryName = D:\\Shop Plan\\ERP Project\\Main Source\\OutPut\\Debug\\DBBackup;

string filePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\prabhu\Desktop\Backup.sql";

TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath);

textWriter.WriteLine("CD " + directoryName);

if (type == "Backup")
{
  textWriter.WriteLine("mysqldump -h " + "SERVERNAME"+ " -u " + "USERNAME" + " -p" + "PASSWORD" + " -P " + "PORT" + " --routines " + "DATABASE_NAME" + " -B> " + filePath);
}

else if (type == "Restore")
{
  textWriter.WriteLine("mysql -h " + "SERVERNAME" + " -u " + "USERNAME" + " -p" + "PASSWORD" +" -P " + "PORT" + " <" + filePath);
}

textWriter.Close();

Process processes = new Process();

processes.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = directoryName ;

processes.StartInfo.FileName = "Backup.BAT";

processes.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

processes.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

processes.Start();

processes.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: What is your exact code to backup/restore database?

Comment: Are you putting the path into some extra ""? Depending on your code you may have to escape the extra ": "\"C:\Documents and Settings\prabhu\Desktop\Backup.sql\""This usually does the trick,

Comment: The question has a really bad formatting and it's hard to understand. Anyway put a @ before the string and double quotes: string filePath = @"""C:\Documents and Settings\prabhu\Desktop\Backup.sql""";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines:

```
string directoryName = D:\\Shop Plan\\ERP Project\\Main Source\\OutPut\\Debug\\DBBackup;

string filePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\prabhu\Desktop\Backup.sql";
```

change to:

```
string directoryName = "\"" + @"D:\Shop Plan\ERP Project\Main Source\OutPut\Debug\DBBackup" + "\"";

string filePath = "\"" + @"C:\Documents and Settings\prabhu\Desktop\Backup.sql" + "\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@"C:\Documents and Settings\prabhu\Desktop\Backup.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is the spaces maybe you need the syntax @
http://www.dotnetperls.com/path